# .Net standard Print Dialog versus Notepad's Print Dialog

Tags: printdialog

In my C# WinForm application, I use a "PrintDialog" to open a standard Window where the user can "customize" his print request (select the printer, access the properties, select to print all pages or a range, ...)

[image: .Net Print Dialog]

But in that window, the user cannot enter a list of pages (separated by ,) that he want to print, just as we can do within notepad's Print Dialog.

[image: Notepad' print dialog]

Any idea how I can get a Print Dialog like the  notepad's PrintDialog ?

[EDIT] As suggested by Brian, the solution is to set the property UseEXDialog to true on PrintDialog. 
That was not obvious based [on the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.useexdialog(v=vs.110).aspx), but it does the trick !

Comment: Did you set this to true? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.useexdialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are repeatedly mentioning *Notepad*, but what you are showing is *WordPad*.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian!!! This property does the trick. I did read the documentation but didn't try all the properties... And the documentation for that one only says : true to indicate the dialog should be shown with the Windows XP style, otherwise false. Which was not IMO clearly related to that field...

Comment: Sorry O.R., I did my test with notepad but took the screenshots from this link http://www.yevol.com/en/vcsharp2005/controls/dlgprint.htm (I didn't know I could upload my own screenshots so easily on StackOverflow and wanted to redirect to existing ones). It's the same print dialog for both applciation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set PrintDialog.UseEXDialog to true.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.useexdialog(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.useexdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Although the documentation of Microsoft is really not explicit, this property does indeed the trick... Thanks a lot again Brian.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, it seems that you should set the [`AllowSomePages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.allowsomepages%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to true.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the Pages option button is enabled.